# Swift. Protocols for delegate pattern in UIKit. NSObjectProtocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

Swift3. I am wondering how exactly `UICollectionViewDelegate` can be declared as a weak property.

If you check swift 'headers' you will see that it inherits from `UIScrollViewDelegate` which in turn inherits from `NSObjectProtocol` which is not marked as `class`-only protocol.

If I try to make my own protocol to use with delegate pattern as `weak` 'delegate' property I get compile time error `'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types`.

While I understand why compiler forces me to use `class`, I am wondering how `UICollectionViewDelegate` can get away with this. I would guess `class` is some kind of syntactic sugar but I would appreciate if you could explain me.

On a side note: Is there a pattern to deal with situations where I really need a protocol which could be adopted by both value and reference types but also "easily" managed from memory point of view (meaning `weak` references).

I am sorry for a bit fuzzy question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the `class` keyword on a `protocol` definition, you're saying "this protocol only applies to classes, not Swift structs or enums."

When an object inherits from, or is, an Objective-C class or protocol, it by definition isn't a Swift struct or enum.  So it doesn't need to specify.